# Is “One-to-One NAT” works in one direction only

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

I have created **One-to-One NAT** rule in my home DSLmodem/router, in order to allow a locally networked PC with web server installed on it and private IP address assigned to it (192.168.1.2) to communicate in the internet with a public IP address given to me by my ISP (197.45.238.x).

[image: Screenshot from the router]

**The good news is:**

Now i can surf the web from that machine using the public IP (Confirmed by visiting web sites like [whatismyipaddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com))

**The bad news:**

I can't access that machine from the internet or ping it.

Can somebody explain what is wrong?

Is one to **One-to-One NAT** works in one direction only?

And how to fix that?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your router’s web UI. It’s likely the setting doesn’t do what you think it does. You’re probably looking for port forwarding (AKA virtual server).

Comment: I have edited my question, you can see now a link for a screenshot for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about one-to-one NAT you will have to define the direction as well.

Example: One-to-one outbound and inbound.

Scenario 1: Any inside machine needs to go online using public IP address is outbound NAT.

Scenario 2: Any machine from outside should come to inside machine using public IP.

From the above image I see that you have created outbound one-to-one NAT policy.

Please create a inbound NAT policy which looks like this:

Original Source: Any
Translated Source: Original
Original Destination: Public IP (Outside IP)
Translated Destination: Inside IP (Webserver IP)
Service: HTTP (TCP80)

This NAT policy will allow any internet request coming to your public IP to reach your inside web server. Hence internet users types your public IP should see your webpage hosted on your local machine on TCP80.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i think that there is no such thing called direction in one-to-one NAT.

Comment: Take a look at the below link, once you click on the link navigate to Network --> NAT policies and check the inbound interface and outbound interface. This defines the direction.


http://nsa6600.demo.sonicwall.com/main.html

Comment: Without direction on what traffic a router / firewall will apply the traffic?

Comment: I don't have direction option in my router. and from what i know you just define the NAT rule (for example, one-to-one or one-to-many...etc) and it just work bidirectional.

Note: i need to configure that on a router not a firewall.